# Activate Child Theme .mo and .po files

Tags: child-theme, translation, localization

I am experiencing some problems while trying to use my dutch .mo and .po files for my child theme.

I have added the following line to `wp-config.php`:

```
define ('WPLANG', 'nl_NL');
```

After that I have placed the .mo and .po files in: `child-theme/languages/`. Lastly I followed a post here on stack exchange and pasted this code in my child theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme','wpse_110727_translate_theme');
function wpse_110727_translate_theme() {
     load_theme_textdomain( 'textdomain', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
     $locale = get_locale();
     $locale_file = get_template_directory() . "/languages/$locale.php";

         if ( is_readable( $locale_file ) ) require_once( $locale_file );
 }
```

After all this, my translation still isn't active on my pages.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a TON of experience loading in text-domains, but I think the problem could be as simple as `get_template_directory()`.

`get_template_directory()` returns the parent directory, while `get_stylesheet_directory()` returns the child theme directory.

Comment: Hi Eric, I tried it, it didn't work. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: The problem is still there, anyone?

Comment: Give us some more information - echo `$locale_file` - is it the correct directory? Also why are you trying to being in a `$locale.php` file? What does that file contain.?

Comment: having a similar issue. Would love to know if you solved this. Using qTranslate together with the localisation plugin and the Dutch nor German translations load in my child theme at the moment. I added nl_NL to wp-config.php as well and made the needed functions.php changes and created the .mos and .pos.